# Android: Task every 10 seconds (exactly)

Tags: android

We have an app who should process a task every `10` seconds. This should be more or less exact, which means that a difference of `1` or `2` seconds is `OK`, but not gaps of `20` seconds or more.

This should work regardless if the app is open, in foreground or in background.

We implement this via `AlarmManager`, but it is not working properly. If the smartphone is not plugged in and it is running in background, there are gaps in the execution.

With `Android 4.3.`, we have gaps (about 30 seconds) from time to time, with `Android 5.x` we have fewer gaps, but gaps about `5` or `10` minutes long!

I think there must be a way to implement this, an alarm clock is also possible and is exact.

More about the app: It works in a service and a broadcast receiver is implemented. This means the service is restarted if I wipe away the app or restart the handy. This works correctly. The only problem is the `10` second task.

Any hints? How is an alarm clock implemented? Which calls, API?

I tried different ways until now without success.

Thanks
Hans

Answer (score 1):

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        PerformBackgroundTask performBackgroundTask = new PerformBackgroundTask();
                        // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask 
                        performBackgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000); //execute in every 10000 ms
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with handler and runnable, which I think is preferred by Android..

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity
{
    private Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable backgroundTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do your background task
            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainHandler.postDelayed(backgroundTask, 10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, no success. There are caps of several seconds or minutes. I don't know why.

The app should work in foreground and in background.

Answer (score -2):

Use of "AlarmManager" with "broadcast Receiver" and "service". These 3 component will make your requirement fulfill.

Using Alarm Manager to generate a Broadcast Receiver, and from BroadcastReceiver start a Service where you can put your desired code of logic to get your task done in every 10 Seconds.

Comment: That's a rather vague and incomplete answer.

Comment: Hi. I try it with the AlarmManager. This works, my Tast is called every 10 seconds. But after a while, it is not called for 5 or 10 minutes! This occurs after the app runs for several minutes or hours, and occurs every hour (more or less). I have no idea why.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked for you. I understand your current problem. This usually happens coz service might get stopped because of lack of resources or some other reason. So to make it run for every time, you need to register for other Broadcast Receivers as well. For Example, you need to register for Wake_up after taking wake_up permissions. So that whenever user start using the phone, your broadcast receiver is called, and you can check whether your desired service is running or not. If not start the service. You can even use sharedprefs to store values of last time service called toast.

Comment: And @Hans if you feel that my answer worked for you, please mark it as right answer. And you can see your further problem solution in above comment. Thanks